# JavaScript getElementsByTagName within specific container

Tags: javascript, dom

In php, I can use getElementsByTagName on any DOM object but it seems JavaScript does not have that concept.

IE if the var detailsNode is a specific node, detailsNode.getElementsByTagName('summary') does not seem to work, firebug error says detailsNode.getElementsByTagName is not a function.

So, how do I target getElementsByTagName() to only look within a specified DOM element in JavaScript?

Thank you for suggestions.

Oh, and the answer needs to be straight up DOM2 method, no jQuery for this (where it would be easy).

Comment: Assuming `detailsNode` is a reference to an element, what you have should work. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName for more details.

Comment: Ah, I guess my bug must be elsewhere. Thanks.

Comment: Doh! I had spelling typo in getElementsByTagName

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Element and Node objects do have getElementsByTagName which returns an array of the found elements in the given Element/Node.

Comment: Yes, I'm terribly embarrassed, the code worked as intended once I fixed a typo.